# Multiple components from object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm very new to reactjs and having a problem which I can't seem to figure out.
It could be that I don't fully understand the concept yet, but well, here goes:
Oh and I know that some of the things are not the best way, but I'm new to react and javascript (which I'm doing for an internship).

I'm working with a modification from the [Facebook react tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). What I have now is: an array of 2d objects, this gets worked over by .map(). 
one object looks something like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Exercise",
  "timeStamp": "2016-03-22T10:08:20.3105358+00:00",
  "data": {"name": "Back training", "video": "v=yoimdckms"}
}
```

another one would look like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "appointment",
  "data": {"appointmentsubject": "have dinner", "label": "green"}
}
```

---

So my problem is this: when just pick component.name and component.timeStamp, it`s fine.

```
var ComponentList = React.createClass({ //this works
  render: function () {
    var componentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(component, index) {
      return (
        <Component name={component.name} timeStamp={component.timestamp} key={index} >
        </Component>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="componentList">
        {componentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

But when I get into the data object, it obviously fails, because not all objects have an appointmentSubject property and others have no video property and can't get a value out of undefined.

```
<Component //this doesn't work
  name={component.name} 
  timeStamp={component.timeStamp}  
  video={component.data.video}
  key={index}>
</Component>
```

So my question is, how do I go about here. 
My solutions (that I have not worked out in code yet) are:

- make a component per name: ExerciseComponent, Appointment etc. (this would require the sorting of components later, by timestamp, this happens now before the components are loaded into the state.)
- Make a Component, with the fields that all components have like name and timestamp, and depending on the name, insert properties.

What I really want to know is: are the solutions that I thought of viable? Or is there another solution that would help me better?

Oh and I don't use flux or redux or whatever, because atm I'm trying to be as minimalistic as possible, because it tends to get confusing very fast.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass the entire `component` to the `Component` and then evaluate there.  So:

```
var ComponentList = React.createClass({ //this works
  render: function () {
    var componentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(component, index) {
      return (
        <Component componentData={component}>
        </Component>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="componentList">
        {componentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Then inside your `Component`, you can evaluate the object and provide default props for any properties that don't exist.  This way, if the object you pass in doesn't have all props, React will provide default props.  For example:

```
const Component = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps(
        return : {
           component: {
               name: 'N/A',
               timestamp: 'N/A',
               data : {}
           }
        }
    ),

    render() {
        return {
            <div>{this.props.component.name}</div>
            <div>{this.props.component.timestamp}</div>
            <div>{this.props.component.data.video}</div>
        };

    }
})
```

Note also that it is possible to add this sort of logic to your `map` function also (the one that is looping over the original array of objects).  In each iteration of your map, you could also build a normalized object, like:

```
jsonArray.map((obj) => {
    return {
        name: obj.name || 'N/A',
        timestamp: obj.timestamp || 'N/A',
        data: {
            video: obj.data.video || 'N/A
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: So what you're saying is, make a component, declare a default name and fill it with the properties that belong to that default name? 
What do you mean by evaluate? Because I can't read that out of your code. Thank you for your answer, I will test and try tomorrow.

Comment: Edited to my answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var componentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(component, index) {
         component.name && component.timeStamp && component.data.video?
      return (
  <Component //this doesn't work
        name={component.name} 
        timeStamp={component.timeStamp}  
        video={component.data.video}
        key={index}>
        </Component>
      ):null
    });
```

Comment: But wouldn´t this just check if there is a video field and if it is, show the component and otherwise wouldn´t show it? That would not show the one with the appointmentSubject.